# BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 283: Method [index] does not exist. Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am getting method does not exist when it actually exists in my controller.

**BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 283:
Method [index] does not exist.**

This is my route:

```
Route::get('products', array(
    'as'=>'products.index',
    'uses'=>'ProductsController@index'));
```

And this is my controller method (index action)

```
public function index()
{  
    $products = Product::all();      
    return products;
}
```

I don't understand why now that I am not even using a resource route. Any assistance please.

Answer (score 2):

Debug your routes. If this is the code of your ProductsController than I guarantee you that your routing doesn't results to this controller. 
Are you sure there are no other routes, namespaces in your routes or middleware that could result in this problem?

What does `php artisan route:list` returns?

Comment: But osme other methods within the same controller seem to work just fine

Comment: Yes, but this answer does seem correct, but if you can not run php artisan route:list - indicates a problem.  You could try installing a new copy of Laravel, using composer, or better yet: use Homebase.  But an earlier defined route is probably catching /products, per this answer.

Comment: I have just fixed the artisan issue, the productscontroller lists correctly in the route list with index() method also listed, I stil get [index] method not found exception

Comment: Can you post your route:list result as there must be anther route that is processed that results in the index not found exception. Your controller is not the problem.